# Avoid syncronous calls in Akka Actors due of Await result

Tags: scala, akka, actor

Because I do some "complex" operations, I think my Actor became asyncronous. The main problem I think is that I use `Await.result` inside the method which return responses.

actor:

```
def process(subscribers: Set[ActorRef]): Receive = {
    case Join(ref) => context become process(subscribers + ref)
    case Leave(ref) => context become process(subscribers - ref)
    case Push(request) =>
        val filteredSubscribers = (subscribers - sender())
            .filter(s => exists(s, request)) // just some actor filters

        filteredSubscribers.foreach { subscriber =>
            // here I have a Map with each actor requests
            val actorOptions = getActorOptions(subscriber) 
            subscriber ? getResponse(actorOptions, request)
        }
}
```

The problem is inside getResponse (I think).

```
getResponse(actorOptions: JsValue, request: SocketRequest): JsValue = {
   (actorOptions \ "dashboardId").asOpt[Int] match {
     case Some(id) => {
        val response = widgetsService.getByDashboadId(id) map { widgets =>
            val widgetsResponse: List[Future[String]] = widgets.map(w => {
                 widgetsService.getDataById(w.id) map {
                    data => s"""{ "widgetId": ${w.id}, "data": $data }"""
                 }
            })

            var responses: List[String] = List.empty

            widgetsResponse.foreach(f => {
                f.onComplete {
                   case Success(value) => responses = value :: responses
                   case Failure(e) => println(s"Something happened: ${e.getMessage}")
                }
            })
            // first time when I use Await.result
            // used to populate the responses list with data from all futures
            Await.result(Future.sequence(widgetsResponse), Duration.Inf)

            Json.parse(s"""{
                "dashboardId": $id, 
                "widgets": [${response.mkString(", ")}]
            }""".stripMargin)
        }
        // second time when I use Await.result
        // used to return a JsValue instead of a Future[JsValue]
        Await.result(response, Duration.Inf)
     }
     case None => buildDefaultJson // return default json value, unimportant for this example
   }
}
```

Due of that, In frontend, if I have 2 sockets clients, the response for the second will be send only after first.
I found that I can obtain a "fake" increase of performance if I embrance the getResponse in a future inside of my Actor.

```
filteredSubscribers.foreach { subscriber =>
   val actorOptions = getActorOptions(subscriber) 
   Future(subscriber ? getResponse(actorOptions, request))
}
```

So, for both `subscribers` the action will be started in same time, but when the first will reach the `Await.result`, the second will be locked until first is done.

I need to avoid using `Await.result` there, but I don't know how to get the results of a list of futures, without using `for-comprehension` (because is a dynamically list) for first time where I use it.

Because Akka `ask` operator (`?`) return a `Future[Any]`, I tried that my `getResponse` method to return directly a `JsValue` to be mapped then in `Future[JsValue]`. If I remove the second `Await.result` and my method will return `Future[JsValue]`, then the actor will return a `Future[Future[JsValue]]` which I don't think is too right.

After some more researches and solutions found on so, my code become:

```
Future.sequence(widgetsResponse) map { responses =>
   Json.parse(
      s"""
         |{
         |"dashboardId": $id,
         |"tableSourceId": $tableSourceId,
         |"widgets": [ ${responses.mkString(", ")}]
         |}""".stripMargin
    )
}
```

`getResponse` returns a `Future[JsValue]` now, removing both `Await.result` cases, and actor case become:

```
filteredSubscribers.foreach { subscriber =>
   val actorOptions = getActorOptions(subscriber) 
      getResponse(actorOptions, request) map { data =>
        subscriber ? data
   }
}
```

I don't know why, still have a synchronous behavior. Damn, this can be due of my subscribers type: `Set[ActorRef]`? I tried to use parallel foreach and this looks like solving my problem:

```
filteredSubscribers.par.foreach { subscriber =>
  val actorOptions = getActorOptions(subscriber) 
     getResponse(actorOptions, request) map { data =>
        subscriber ? data
  }
}
```

Comment: Out of interest, how many CPU cores are you running this service with?  I ask because the only reason "when the first will reach the Await.result, the second will be locked until first is done" is if you only have 1 thread in the dispatcher/execution context you're using.

Comment: I tested only on localhost, which is a macos with 2ghz quad-core intel i5. I tested using println with messages before and after getResponse(), I don't know a better way for that :d